ASP.NET Core reporting - allow external images
I have problem with external images in my project; I have a .rdlc file, and I need to load images from a database, but I have only the name of the file like logo.png in the database, the files are in a folder C:/Images.
In the .rdlc designer, I try to do this:

and my view model works in dotvvm:

but I can't add localReport.EnableExternalImages = true; because of an error

LocalReport does not contain a definition EnableExternalImages

Can somebody help me? I would be very happy for that.
I try the localreport.EnableExternalImages = true, but in .NET Core, it's  not working and try find in RDLC designer the options

I found the solutation, just add this code after declaration of your localreport
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(PathYourReport);

enter image description here
